# what is a bar tip in the context of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to reproduce the table/figure in this [CMU Machine Learning lecture](https://youtu.be/He_D2KWXyQU?t=1131).

per [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), params `xerr, yerr` in `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` is to add horizontal / vertical errorbars to the **bar tips**.

what is a bar tip? is it somewhere on the top of the bar? I [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bar%20tips%20matplotlib%22) and didn't find anything related.

Comment: Bar tips means the end of the bars.    Think "fingertips".  It means to the end of the bars.  The errorbars will appear half on the bar other half off the bar.  The tip of the bars.

Comment: @ScottBoston  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bar tips means the end of the bar.  Think "fingertips".  The errorbars will appear on the end of the bar with half on the bar the other half off the bar.  The tip of the bar.